# assign all items of an array except those of the given indices

Tags: python, numpy

An example will tell things straight forward:

```
import numpy

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Edit:
# commenting out below `a` assignation for the more general case as shown 
#+below this commented block
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# a = np.array(range(8))
# print a
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

a = np.random.randn(8)
print a
array([-0.53683985, -0.321736  ,  0.15684836,  0.32085469,  1.99615701,
       -1.16908367, -0.10995894, -1.90925978])
b = [4, 7]
#    ^  ^  These values are indices of values in `a` I want to keep unchanged

# I want to set all values to, 
# say np.random.random_integers(10, 100) or simply `nan` except for indices given by `b`:
# So I want something like this:
a[: (!b)] = np.random.random_integers(10, 100)  # I'm using "!" as the NOT operator 
print a
array([62, 96, 47, 74, 1.99615701, 32, 11, -1.90925978])
# not changed:         ^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^
# or:
a[: (!b)] = np.nan
print a
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.99615701, nan, nan, -1.90925978])
# not changed:             ^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I know I can use np.ma.array(a, mask = False) and a.mask[b] = True, but from this point I don't know how to assign my random numbers to only unmasked values

Comment: I think the question is now quite clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply mask and update *elements* of `a` that are not in `b`,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.range(8)
b = [4, 7]
a[~np.in1d(a, b)] = np.random.random_integers(
    10, 100, size=len(a) - len(b))
print a
> array([34, 16, 99, 67,  4, 32, 64,  7])
```

The key is the `~np.in1d(a, b)` construct. `np.in1d(a, b)` makes an array, the size of `a` such that item `i` of this array is only true if `a[i]` is in `b`; the `~` reverses this.

Also note that the size passed to np.random.random_integers has to match the size of the masked a.

What the asker wants is to pass random numbers to `a` for *indices* of `a` that are not in `b`. Now, if you wanted to assign random integers to the elements in `b`, you could simply do `a[b] = ...`. Excluding them is more complicated. The way to do it is this:

```
a[~np.in1d(np.arange(np.size(a), b))] = np.random.random_integers(
                                             10, 100, size=len(a) - len(b))
```

which is similar to the `a[...] = ...` assignment in the first part of this answer, except instead of passing `a` to `np.in1d`, `np.arange` is used to make an array that gives indices, not elements, of `a` to `np.in1d`.

Comment: Instead of `np.logical_not([i in b for i in a])`, you could write `~np.in1d(a,b)`.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the right one but I need a little change so as `b` is understood as a list of indices not values. In fact my example is too confusing; I should have initially filled `a` with, for example float random numbers while keeping `b` unchanged because it is the list of indices in `a` which values I want to keep unchanged.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify how to do what you want. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than being parsimonious with the generation of random numbers -- especially if `b` is a small list -- it would be easier to just generate a random array of size `a.size`, and then copy the desired values of `a` into the new array, `c`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(8))
b = [4, 7]
c = np.random.random_integers(10, 100, size=a.size)
c[b] = a[b]
a = c
print(a)
```

yields something like

```
[10 92 73 66  4 54 42  7]
```

Comment: you solved the problem for the particular case of my example; my use of numpy.random.random_integers was only to have some numbers. In the real case I'm not using specifically numpy.random.random_integers. It could be anything. My goal is really to fill a given array with given values except for indices I specified in another variable.